# How do you `pip freeze` without installing the packages?

Tags: python, pip

The only way I know how to freeze the requirements of a Python project is rather arduous:

1. Create a fresh virtualenv
2. Install all of the requirements (a potentially IO and CPU intensive process that may also require external dependencies for libraries whose install involves compiling C)
3. Run `pip freeze`

How do you go directly from a `requirements.txt` to a frozen requirements file, without all of the expensive side effects?

---

For example, if `requirements.txt` looks like this:

```
abc
```

where `abc` is a project that depends on another project called `xyz`, and I run `pip [something] > requirements_frozen.txt`, then `requirements_frozen.txt` might look like:

```
abc==0.1
xyz==2.3
```

Comment: Isn't a requirements.txt file and frozen requirements.txt file the same thing? `pip freeze` creates a frozen requirements.txt file? Could you explain a bit more on what you're looking to do. Thx

Answer (score 1):

The [pip-tools](https://github.com/nvie/pip-tools) library includes a command called `pip-compile` which does this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pipreqs`. It does just that - "and sometimes you just need to create requirements.txt for a new project without installing modules."

https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs

Comment: `pipreqs` generates a list of requirements based on imports, not based on a list of requirements.